# Getting firestore collection array in to data entity

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

I'm new in Android Kotlin and I want to GET an array of **help** in Firestore into my entity and this is my code:

```
val appCollection = App.context.db.collection("app")
    val docApp = appCollection.document("info")
    docApp.get().addOnCompleteListener { task ->
        if (task.isSuccessful) {
            val document = task.result
            if (document.exists()) {
                val list = document["help"] as List<*>?
            }
        }
    }
```

how can i put that list into my entity, and this is my Entity

```
class Info() : Parcelable{

var help: List<Help>? = null
var howto: List<HowTo>? = null
var info: List<Info>? = null
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I see in your screenshot, your `help` array contains objects of type String and **not** objects of type `Help`. To read such an array, please change the following field declaration from:

```
var help: List<Help>? = null
```

To:

```
var help: List<String>? = null
```

If you however need to store `Help` in the array, then you need to first add such objects accordingly. So your structure might look like this:

```
Firestore-root
  |
  --- app (collection)
       |
        --- info (document)
             |
             --- help (array)
                  |
                  --- 0
                      |
                      --- fieldOne: valueOne
                      |
                      --- fieldTwo: valueOTwo
```

To map such an array to a List of custom objects, please check the following article:

- [How to map an array of objects from Cloud Firestore to a List of objects?](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-map-an-array-of-objects-from-cloud-firestore-to-a-list-of-objects-122e579eae10)

Comment: You're very welcome, Andika.